# CakePHP error: "Unable to import DataSource class .DboSource"

Tags: database, cakephp

I was working locally on my computer on a cakephp project for 3 days. Then i had to shut off the computer. In the morning, when i turned it on, and tried to continue work, i got error:

```
Fatal Error (256): ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - 
Unable to import DataSource class .DboSource 
[CORE/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php, line 185]
```

What could be the problem? I haven't changed any of the DB settings. I tried them out with a db manager and they work. I googled this in different ways, but couldn't find the answer.

Any clue would be awesomely appreciated!

Update: I noticed that if i drop the database, or change user/pass to something wrong, this error doesn't change. (..if that helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the database settings didn't matter, I figured out it was a problem in the system files in cakephp.

So I went ahead and downloaded again the same version 1.3.10 and replaced all over the `cake/`, `plugins/`, and `vendors/` folders, in which I hadn't changed anything anyway. I only kept my `app/` folder.

Finally it's up again.